# Generate .proto file from a custom RuntimeTypeModel in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Using [protobuf-net](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fprotobuf-net%2F&ei=t5SBVeLAB4TwUNOMgIAI&usg=AFQjCNED9rBjO40OTE7lOqea_rCnfa1Gsg&sig2=HrNDmN9c9k0AgQbGtBgrKA&bvm=bv.96041959,d.d24), I wish to generate a .proto file from a type model other than `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`:

```
RuntimeTypeModel myModel = TypeModel.Create();
myModel.Add(typeof(MyClass), true);
...
string myProto = Serializer.GetProto<MyClass>(); // Does not work, as it references RuntimeTypeModel.Default
```

- How can I generate a .proto file in this case?
- Inferring from the source code of `GetProto()`, should I simply call `myModel.GetSchema(typeof(MyClass))`?

Answer (score 1):

Since no one answered so far:
Calling `myModel.GetSchema(typeof(MyClass))` did work, though I'm not sure this is the correct method.